# rate of convergence central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X_{1},X_{2,\ldots }$ be i.i.d. with finite second moment random variables. With mean $\mu$ and $\sigma^{2}$
Then the classical CLT states:
$\sqrt{n}(\overline{X_{n}}-\mu)$ convergences to $N(0,\sigma^{2})$ in distribution.
Therefore, statisticians usually claim that the convergence in probability, 
$\overline{X_{n}}$ to $\mu$, holds with the rate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

My Questions are:

Can someone give a detailed explanation of that fact?
Isn't it necessary, that the r.vs have finite third moment in order to be able to make statements about the rate of convergence? (Using Berry Esseen)

Comment: Convergence  of $\bar X_n$ to $\mu$ is different from convergence of $\sqrt n(\bar X_n-\mu)$ to $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Statisticians talk about the former.

Comment: I thought that the CLT specifies the speed of convergence in the Law of Large numbers? 
But why statisticians talk about the rate of convergence, without assuming finite third moments?

Comment: CLT describes rate of convergence of LLN - not rate of convergence of CLT itself - which is a different question. You just need the finite second moment for CLT to hold.

Comment: So in order to describe the rate of convergence in the CLT one needs Berry Esseen Type Theorems?

Comment: The convergence rate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ in the LLN is a "convergence rate in probability", right? Since
$\left|\overline{X_{n}}-\mu\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}Z$, where $Z\sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$ Since $Z$ is not a constant I call this rate a rate in probability.

Comment: You don't even need CLT. Chebyshev yields $P(|\bar X_n-\mu|>\epsilon)<\frac {\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2 n}$ - falls of at rate $1/n$ for fixed $\epsilon$. If you want to keep probability of deviation constant, then $\epsilon\sim n^{-1/2}$.

Comment: So whenever we have a sequence $X_{n}$ with $X_{n}\rightarrow\mu$ in probability. And $\alpha_{n}(X_{n}-\mu)\rightarrow N(..,..)$ hols. Then $\alpha_{n}$ is the rate of convergence, right?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to chat on this issue, because I don't have enough points.