# Proof of formula in State-space linear models

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stationary-processes

A linear, discrete-time, stationary, state-space model is
$$
\begin{cases}
x_{t+1} = F x_t + v_t \ &t=0,1,2\dots \\
y_t = H x_t + w_t \ &t=1,2,3,\dots
\end{cases}
$$
where:

- $F \in \mathbb{C}^{n_x \times n_x}$ is a stable matrix ($|\lambda_i(F)| < 1$  for all $i$);
- $x_t \in \mathbb{C}^{n_x \times 1}$ is the state vector;
- $y_t \in \mathbb{C}^{n_y \times 1}$ is the measurement vector;
- $v_t, w_t$ are random vectors (additive noise) which admit a PDF (Probability Density Function);

The noise terms are zero-mean and:
$$
\forall t_1 \neq t_2 : \ v_{t_1} \perp v_{t_2}, w_{t_1} \perp w_{t_2} \\
\forall t_1, t_2 : \ v_{t_1} \perp w_{t_2} \\
\forall t : \ E[v_t v_t^\dagger] = Q, E[w_t w_t^\dagger] = R
$$
where $X \perp Y$ means that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $^\dagger$ means conjugate-transpose, and $Q,R$ are assumed to be positive definite hermitian matrices. The initial condition $x_0$ is an absolutely continuous random vector satisfying $E[x_0] = \mathbf{0}, x_0 \perp v_t, x_0 \perp w_t$ for any $t$.

The following formula requires proof:
$$
(*) \quad f(x_t, y_t | X_{0:t-1}, Y_{1:t-1}) = f(x_t|x_{t-1}) f(y_t|x_t)
$$
where $f(\cdot)$ denotes the PDF, $X_{0:t-1} = (x_{t-1}, x_t, \dots, x_0)$, $Y_{1:t} = (y_t, y_{t-1},\dots,y_1)$. How to prove it?

---

It is clear that $x_t$ is a Markov process, so
$$
f(x_t | X_{0:t-1}) = f(x_t|x_{t-1})
$$
but how can we use this to prove $(*)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
f(x_t, y_t | X_{0:t-1}, Y_{1:t-1}) &= f(x_t | X_{0:t-1}, Y_{1:t-1}) f(y_t |x_t, X_{0:t-1}, Y_{1:t-1}) \\
&= f(x_t | x_{t-1}) f(y_t |x_t),
\end{align}
$$
where the first line follows from the definition of conditional probability, and the latter line follows from the fact that once you know $x_{t-1}$, $X_{0:t-2}, Y_{1:t-1}$ is uninformative about $x_t$ (by the independence assumption), and, likewise, once you know $x_t$, $X_{0:t-1}, Y_{1:t-1}$ is uninformative about $y_t$ (again by the independence assumption).

Note that in the proof, you're not directly using the fact that $x_t$ is Markov, instead, you're using something that is proved in a similar way that you would establish that $x_t$ is Markov. I.e. we need that the distribution of $x_t|x_{t-1}$ is independent of $x_{t-2},x_{t-3},\dots$ and $y_{t-1},y_{t-2},\dots$, which follows directly from the equations of the state space model and the independence of $v_t$, $w_t$ across time. The independence of the distribution of $y_t|x_t$ from $x_{t-1},x_{t-2},\dots$ and $y_{t-1},y_{t-2},\dots$ also follows directly from the equations of the state space model and the independence of $v_t$, $w_t$ across time.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. The independence assumption I believe is stated or probably implicit. I am not following the first line: how can you read $P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B)$ there? Also, $f(y_t | x_t, X_{0:t-1}, Y_{1:t-1}) = f(y_t|x_t)$ is intuitively clear, but I am not sure, since $y_t$ is not Markov (unlike $x_t$). Can you add a bit more detail for that?

Comment: The rule you stated holds also for conditional distributions. $P(A,B|C)=P(A|B,C)P(B|C)$. Here, $B=x_t$, $A=y_t$, $C=(X_{0:t-1},Y_{1:t-1})$.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail on the second line. Does that help?

Comment: Ok, now first line is very clear. What is the ''law of motion'', ''independence of the shocks'' ?

Comment: Perhaps that's econometric language. I've clarified now. By the "law of motion" I was referring to the equations of the state space model. And by the independence of shocks I was referring to the independence of v and w across time.