# $E[X\mid F_n] \to X$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading on

[Convergence in distribution of conditional expectations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287254/convergence-in-distribution-of-conditional-expectations)

Let $X$ be integrable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and assume $\mathcal{F}_n \uparrow \mathcal{F}$. Then, 
$$E(X \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \to X \ \ \text{a.s.}$$

And I was wondering if this is claim is true? Is it a well known fact? Has the theorem a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is one version of [Doob's martingale convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems).