# On the rate of convergence of the central limit theorem

Tags: statistics, approximation, central-limit-theorem

As I have seen, there are many questions on this site concerning the rate of convergence of the central limit theorem: for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532602/rate-of-convergence-central-limit-theorem), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166338/meaning-of-rate-of-convergence-in-central-limit-theorems), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1959350/is-there-a-rate-of-convergence-for-the-central-limit-theorem), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269992/rate-of-convergence-in-the-central-limit-theorem-lindeberg-l%C3%A9vy). In particular, the [third question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1959350/is-there-a-rate-of-convergence-for-the-central-limit-theorem) of this list concerns quantitative bounds on the convergence in distribution

$$
\frac{\overline{X}_n - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \to_D Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).
$$

One commenter points out the [Berry-Essen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) which gives a bound on the CDF of $(\overline{X}_n - \mu)/(\sigma/\sqrt{n})$ and the standard normal random variable based on the third absolute moment $\rho := \Bbb E[|X-\mu|^3]$. Specifically, if $F_n$ is the CDF of $(\overline{X}_n - \mu)/(\sigma/\sqrt{n})$ and $\Phi$ of the standard normal random variable, then the theorem states that the difference between these is bounded as

$$
|F_n(x) - \Phi(x)| \le \frac{C\rho}{\sigma^3\sqrt{n}}, \text{ for all } x \in \Bbb R, \text{ $C$ constant}.
$$

However, despite the existence of a concrete quantitative error bound on the approximation of $(\overline{X}_n - \mu)/(\sigma/\sqrt{n})$, introductory statistics classes often treat $(\overline{X}_n - \mu)/(\sigma/\sqrt{n})$ as either unapproximable at all by a normal random variable or perfectly normal, with $n = 30$ as a seemingly arbitrary cutoff between the two. Presumably, whether a given sample should be approximated as normal depends highly on $\rho$ and $\sigma$, not just $n$.

My questions:

1. Why isn't the error in the normal approximation taken into account when performing statistical inference or making confidence intervals using the CLT?
2. Does computing

$$
\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \: s := \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2},
$$

and some unbiased consistent estimate $\hat{\rho}$ of $\rho$ and computing $C\hat{\rho}/s^3\sqrt{n}$ give a "better" heuristic for whether one should use a large sample CLT approximation than simply looking at $n\ge 30$? If so, why is $n\ge 30$ approximation so ubiquitous in introductory statistics classes?

Comment: Good question, with theoretical and practical partial answers.  One practical reason is that it's too much trouble, often, or thought to be too much trouble.   Often, especially in applied work, the premises that put us in CLT land are not really believable (the summands aren't *really* independent, they are not *really* independent, and so on) so one shouldn't waste effort on this kind of spurious precision.

Comment: @kimchilover If $\rho/\sigma^3$ is very large, the a priori error bound the CLT approximation could be arbitrarily bad, dominating other sources of error by several orders of magnitude. I imagine for "real data", $\rho/\sigma^3$ must not be that large then?

Comment: $\rho =\mathbb E[|X-\mu|^3]$ is not a common statistic. I think for a normal distribution it may be $\sqrt{\dfrac{8}{\pi}}\sigma^3$ but I have not come across that before